Tkinter Inheritance
I am coding a Scrabble GUI in Tkinter but have run into a problem. I have written a lot of code already but each time I run it, it says Attribute Error: Frame has no attribute letterBag.
Below I have written two versions of the relevant code. One has the Tkinter GUI code alongside it, one doesn't. The error only appears in the code which has the Tkinter stuff.
I know that Python and Tkinter use object references to refer to classes and widgets respectively but this might not be quite accurate?
I am thinking that Tkinter is somehow overriding the object reference so instead of passing the App class reference as a parameter, it passes the main Tk window which is fine when passing the value into the constructor for the new LetterRack Frame but when an attribute belonging just to the App class such as letterBag is referenced, it doesn't belong to the master attribute of the LetterRack class since that only refers to the Tkinter window. Am I correct?
Code 1 without Tkinter GUI implemented:
import random as r

class App:
    def __init__(self):
        self.letterBag = LetterBag()
        self.letterRack = LetterRack(self)

class LetterBag:
    def __init__(self):
        self.tilesLeft = 10
        self.tileList = ["" for x in range(10)]
        
    def remove_tile(self):
        self.tilesLeft -= 1
        return self.tileList.pop(r.randint(0,self.tilesLeft))

class LetterRack:
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master = master #Master would be used for Tkinter widget instantiation
        self.tiles = []
        self.replenish_tiles()

    def replenish_tiles(self):
        while self.master.letterBag.tilesLeft != 0 and len(self.tiles) < 7:
            self.add_tile()
        
    def add_tile(self):
        self.tiles.append("3")

Code 2 with Tkinter GUI as well:
import random as r
import tkinter as tk

class App(tk.Tk): # Main class for the whole game
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__() #Intiate tk.Tk() window
        self.configure(bg="#50c878")
        self.title("Scrabble")
        self.resizable(False,False)
        self.containerFrame1 = tk.Frame(master=self,bg="#50c878",width=43,height=100)
        self.containerFrame2 = tk.Frame(master=self,bg="#50c878",width=63,height=100)
        self.letterBag = LetterBag()
        self.letterRack = LetterRack(self.containerFrame1)
        self.letterRack.grid(row=1,column=0,pady=(1,2),padx=(2,1))
        self.containerFrame1.grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.containerFrame2.grid(row=0,column=1)
        self.mainloop()

class LetterBag:
    def __init__(self):
        self.tilesLeft = 10
        self.tileList = ["" for x in range(10)]
        
    def remove_tile(self):
        self.tilesLeft -= 1
        return self.tileList.pop(r.randint(0,self.tilesLeft))

class LetterRack(tk.Frame): #Class defining letter rack frame
    def __init__(self,master):
        super().__init__(master=master,bg="#FFFFFF",width=40,height=40)
        self.master = master
        self.tiles = []
        self.replenish_tiles()

    def replenish_tiles(self):
        while self.master.letterBag.tilesLeft != 0 and len(self.tiles) < 7:
            self.add_tile()
    
    def add_tile(self):
        pass

window = App()


I had my initial question answered by Raul Sanchez below. I have edited this question to make it completely different since I am not allowed to ask any more questions until I have improved my other questions. While I appreciate this is not in the spirit of the website, I am on a tight timer and editing my previous questions will not affect anything really (since you wouldn't read a downvoted question and therefore wouldn't upvote the changes) until too late. I hope this makes sense

Not that self.master (inside LetterRack) in first code block is the instance of App, but it is a frame inside App for the second code block.

You could use the method place in order to adjust the label correspoding to the element 1.
The code:
    # Crear frame and pack it
    self.test = tk.Frame(self, width=60, height=40, bg=COLOUR) 
    self.test.pack_propagate(False)
    self.test.pack(pady=20, padx=20)

    # Crear label for "A"
    self.testletter = tk.Label(self.test, bg=COLOUR, text="A", font=("Helvetica", 16, "bold"))
    self.testletter.place(x=5, y=5)

    # Crear a label for "1"
    self.testsubscript = tk.Label(self.test, bg=COLOUR, text="1", font=("Helvetica", 8, "bold"))
    
    # Ajust "1" below "A"
    self.testsubscript.place(x=23, y=20)`


Thank you, the first time I have had a response that hasn't criticised my question writing (which I'm not saying can't be improved). I will test it out. Thank you very much.
